# What does "2×4" refer when talking about food?

Tags: touring, nutrition

This post repeatedly uses "2×4" when referring to food eaten on a long, multiday tour. I suspect it's a shorthand for nutritional guidelines when planning meals but it's hard to Google for. What does this refer to?

> Our route headed past Devil’s Punch Bowl and climbed into the clouds powered by the 2×4 of eggs, hashbrowns, bacon and stack of pancakes

http://tenspeedhero.com/features/crush-the-coast/

Comment: Four items x two serves

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about road food, not about bikes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the ratio of protein to carbs

Comment: Aha that makes sense but why is it not "reduced"? Is it 2 servings of protein and 4 of carbs? I'm obviously not looking for actionable nutritional advice just curious!

Comment: Can you explain that and  maybe link to some details please. I still have no idea how the numbers translate to anything I could do.

Comment: Yes, they mean servings and I assume they don't reduce it because it's an easy way to remember. "Build a foundation for your ride" type thing.

First understand that fueling is different for everyone. There's always some trial and error til you find out what works best for you.
Personally, I can't eat as big a breakfast as they mention in the article but the ratio of proteins and carbs is similar. Just a smaller portion.

Comment: Good general info:
http://www.bicycling.com/food/nutrition/best-breakfast-your-ride

More specific:
http://www.hammernutrition.com/knowledge/what-to-eat-pre-race.2981.html?sect=advanced-knowledge-section

Comment: Can you edit your comments into your answer please?